# C# Operator with string/bool

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im still trying to understand how C# works, and now Im stuck not knowing how to use the C# Operator || (conditional-OR)

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider positionCol) {
    if (positionCol.gameObject.tag == "pos_4")
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);  
        Debug.Log ("i hit and destroyed" + positionCol.tag);
    }
    else if (positionCol.gameObject.tag == "pos_3" || "pos_2" || "pos_1" )
    {
        Debug.Log ("i hit " + positionCol.tag);
    }
}
```

It keep telling me that I cant use || for bool and string. How can I do this the simplest of ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand the condition like this:

```
 else if (positionCol.gameObject.tag == "pos_3" || 
          positionCol.gameObject.tag == "pos_2" || 
          positionCol.gameObject.tag == "pos_1")
```

Or possibly use a [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx):

```
switch (positionCol.gameObject.tag)
{
    case "pos_4":
        Destroy(this.gameObject);  
        Debug.Log ("i hit and destroyed" + positionCol.tag);
        break;
    case "pos_3":
    case "pos_2":
    case "pos_1":
        Debug.Log ("i hit " + positionCol.tag);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `positionCol.gameObject.tag == "pos_3"` is of `bool` type, and
`"pos_2"` and `"pos_1"` are strings so the compiler does not allow you
to apply || on these operands. This is normal.

The following is valid

`else if (positionCol.gameObject.tag == "pos_3" || positionCol.gameObject.tag = "pos_2" || positionCol.gameObject.tag = "pos_1" )`

so this is how you can fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should seperate your statement as mentioned in the other answers. Or if you have more string literals to check and you want less code you can do the following:

```
var values = new string[] {"pos_3", "pos_2", "pos_1"};
if(values.Contains(positionCol.gameObject.tag))
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# `||` operator should be applied to equality expressions.

That's why `x == "a" || "b" || "c"` won't work.

It should be:

```
x == "a" || x == "b" || x == "c"
```

Since just `"a"` is a **string literal**, `||` operator cannot be applied to this case. It's like saying *is "a" true?*.

`x == "a"` is a boolean expression because it can be either eval `true` or `false`.

For example:

```
string x = "a";
bool isTrue = x == "a"; // Yes, it's true!
```

Using a modern approach, there's a more elegant solution using a bit of LINQ extension methods:

```
    ...
    else if (new [] { "pos_3", "pos_2", "pos_1" }.Any(text => positionCol.gameObject.tag == text))
    {
        Debug.Log ("i hit " + positionCol.tag);
    }
```

`Any(...)` will check if some of array items (or just any collection or an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`) return `true` for a given boolean expression.

Other example of this use case of `Any`:

```
// Any will return "true", as at least one number is greater than 0!
new int[] { 3, 44, 1, 5, 188 }.Any(number => number > 0);
```

Learn more about `Any` [following this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh yeah - instead of showing him the syntax for a simple `if` statement, confuse him by using as much LINQ as possible!

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I've re-updated... hahaha. Well, thanks for the hint, you're right........!

Comment: In his use case it may not be appropriate to allocate a new array of vales and generate a LINQ object for a simple comparison as he is obviously using Unity3D engine and depending on where he uses his code `OnTriggerEnter` may be triggered pretty often per frame per second, which is especially an issue with Unity3D used on Mobile Platforms with it's outdated Mono 2.6 and awful garbage collection capabilities, causing stutter while the GC happens, which is NOT a nice think in a mobile game.

Comment: @Tseng About the new array of values... This can be easily avoided by just declaring possible values as a class reference... About the part of Unity3D and it's drawbacks, well, I believe OP should re-tag the question, because it's not about Unity3D. Maybe my suggestion wouldn't be the best solution ever on gaming, but at least OP will know some new approach that may be useful in other kind of developments where optimization isn't critical. What do you think?

Comment: Well, while the question/issue is not strictly Unity3D related, the context in which he uses it is (`OnTriggerEnter` is a method used in Unity3D). Using Linq in a method that's potentially called multiple times per frame isn't very good, since LINQ uses enumerators internally  and the overhead of creating enumberators may over weight a simple comparison. Unless his requirement is that the list of values to be compared has to be *dynamic*